# UITableViewCell works differently on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

Folks it appears that **setSelected:animated:** works differently on iPhone and iPad, even in simulator.  Consider the code below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)  {
            //[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES]; works only on iPhone, but not on iPad
              [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES]; //works everywhere
    return;
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

}

it appears this line works only on iPhones

```
[cell setSelected:NO animated:YES];
```

I was wondering if anybody could provide some information on **setSelected:animated:** method's limitations?

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. Does the same thing happen with `setHighlighted:animated:`?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work on the iPad? What behavour are you seeing when it is called on the iPad?

Comment: If you are trying to suppress the default behaviour of highlighting cells when they are tapped, you could uncheck "Show Selection On Touch" in Interface Builder.

Comment: @GregInYEG On iPad nothing happens. The cell remains to be selected.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos  I don't use Interface builder.

Comment: @bioffe: Then maybe you can set the `allowsSelection` property in code.

Comment: The method setSelected:animated works? It didn't work at iPhone before. Thank you for your information.

Comment: @bioffe: Also note that the user interface guidelines recommend deselecting the cell when `someViewController` is popped.

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos It is set by default to YES.

Comment: @bioffe: I know. My suggestion was to set it to `NO`. Also note that it is just a suggestion. I don't know if it will also prevent calling your selection handler, and I don't if you are trying to always prevent the table cell from highlighting, in which case my suggestion may be valid, or simply follow the usual guidelines of deselecting cells that result in a sub view being pushed, in which case you should follow Apple's recommendation instead (which includes using `deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:`.)

Comment: @Marcelo Cantos 'deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:' works fine. I am just wondering whats wrong with 'setSelected:animated:'. It even works on everything but iPad :)

Comment: I tried swapping out deSelectRow for setSelected, and got the same behavior: works on iPhone simulator, not on iPad simulator.  I tried just cell.selected = NO; and that works fine on both.  Looks like a real bug there.

Comment: But does this occur on an actual device? I never trust the simulator.

Comment: @Mark Adams Yes, it refuses to unselect on the actual devices, just like in simulator. It works correctly in iPhone compatibility mode on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's by design on iPads since UITableViews aren't really intended to be used outside of UISplitViewControllers.

If using a UITableView in viewControllers[0] consider how the UITableViewCell will remain to be selected while the user is interacting with the UIViewController in viewControllers[1].

*edit*

I can't support this at all... I looked it up in the HIG and it says nothing like what I mentioned.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451